Safari stops loading web pages (iMac 27" late 2013 with Catalina)
When I'm using Safari, it will eventually stop loading web pages. To be more precise, although Safari is not frozen (all menus work normally, no spinning wheel, etc.), when I try to load a web page it apparently starts loading (I get the blue progress bar in the address window) but the page never loads (the progress bar is always at about 10% of its length).
The problem persists if I restart Safari, even when pressing the Option key at restart. In fact, after this problem starts, pages won't load in Safari until I restart my Mac. It doesn't seem to be a network problem, since pages load fine with Firefox.
Background: I am running the latest version of macOS Catalina on an old (late 2013) iMac 27".
Some time ago I installed Sophos antivirus and Little Snitch, but I uninstalled them, following the procedure advised by the software providers some time ago.
